# После каждого 6 пробела поставить точку. PHP

Tags: php

Существует такой текст

> мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби и саночки возить

Нужно сделать так, чтобы после каждого 6 пробела поставить точку, а следующий символ становился с большой буквы.

Конечный результат был таковым

> мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби. И саночки возить

Comment: К слову, у вас пробел заменяется НЕ на точку...

Comment: Похоже, вам надо поставить точку после 6-го слова в предложении. А потом все новые предложения начать с заглавной.

Comment: Исправила. Спс за уточнение

Answer (score 3):

> Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$str = 'мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби и саночки возить.';

$exp = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ($exp as $k => $item) {
    if ($k > 0 && !($k % 6)) {
        $exp[--$k] = $exp[$k] .'.';
        $temp = preg_split('~~u', $item, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $temp[0] = mb_strtoupper($temp[0], 'UTF-8');
        $exp[++$k] = join($temp);
    }
}

echo join(' ', $exp);
```

`мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби. И саночки возить`

Comment: Ваш вариант идеальный для моего случая. Спасибо.

Comment: @Ершова тогда отметьте его галкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби и саночки возить";

$arr = explode(" ", $str);

for ($i = 6; $i < sizeof($arr); $i += 6) {
    $arr[$i-1] = $arr[$i-1] . ".";
    $arr[$i] = mb_convert_case($arr[$i], MB_CASE_TITLE);
}

echo join(" ", $arr);
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/549b2f06f7c5f0ec70d17e81d2a4c511aca024d3)

Comment: ваш вариант на кириллице не сработает.

Comment: Этот вариант прекрасно работает с кириллицей.

Comment: @Эдуард Почему?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin по вашему, это прекрасная работа? [смотреть демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20b131ec1a46cff56e33b22d5d6259bce89fcb6d)

Comment: @Ilja Denisovs смотрите пример из предыдущего комментария

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо за _полезный_ и _содержательный_ ответ. Пример исправил.

Comment: @IljaDenisovs всегда пожалуйста )

Answer (score 0):

Вот как вариант, писал можно сказать на коленке, проверяйте.

```
$str = "мама мыла раму хочешь кататься люби и саночки возить";
$countSpace = explode(' ' , $str);
$result = "";

for($i = 0; $i < count($countSpace); $i++)
{
  if($i > 0 && $i%5 == 0)
    {
      $countSpace[$i] = str_replace($countSpace[$i], $countSpace[$i].". ", $countSpace[$i]);//$result .= str_replace($countSpace[$i], $countSpace[$i].", ", $countSpace[$i]);
    }
  else if($i > 0 && $i%6 == 0)
    {
      $string = $countSpace[$i];
      $char = mb_strtoupper(substr($string,0,2), "utf-8");
      $string[0] = $char[0];
      $string[1] = $char[1];
      $countSpace[$i] = $string." ";
    }
  else
    {
      $countSpace[$i] = $countSpace[$i]." ";
    }

  $result .= $countSpace[$i];
}

echo $result;
```